# Writing out arrays fixes a problem for a reason unknown to me

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When I run certain programs using FORTRAN 77 with the GNU gfortran compiler I have come across the same problem several times and I'm hoping someone has insight. The value I want should be ~ 1, but it writes out at the end of a program as something well over 10^100. This is generally a problem restricted to arrays for me. The improper value often goes away when I write out the value of this at some stage in the program before (which inevitably happens in trying to troubleshoot the issue).

I have tried initializing arrays explicitly and have tried some array bound checking as well as some internal logical checks in my program. The issue, to me and my research supervisor, seems to be pathological.

```
      WRITE(*,*)"OK9999", INV,INVV
```

vs

```
      WRITE(*,*)"OK9999", INV,INVV,NP,I1STOR(NP),I2STOR(NP)
```

The former gives incorrect results for what I would expect for the variables INV and INVV, the latter correct. This is the 'newest' example of this problem, which has on and off affected me for about a year.

The greater context of these lines is:

```
  WRITE(*,*)"AFTER ENERGY",I1STOR(1),I2STOR(1)
  DO 167 NP=1!,NV

    IF(I1STOR(NP).NE.0) THEN
      INV = I1STOR(NP)
      INVV = I2STOR(NP)
      WRITE(*,*)"OK9999", INV,INVV,NP,I1STOR(NP),I2STOR(NP)
      PAUSE
    ENDIF
```

I1STOR(1) and I2STOR(1) are written correctly in the first case "AFTER ENERGY" above. If I write out the value of NP after the DO 167 line, this will also remedy the situation.

My expectation would be that writing out a variable wouldn't affect its value. Often times I am doing large, time-intensive calculations where the ultimate value is way off and in many cases it has traced back to the situation where writing the value out (to screen or file) magically alleviates the problem. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Please use tag fortran for all Fortran questions. Your situation is very common and hints there is memory corruption. Use all error checking features of your compiůer. Especiaůly array bounds checking, you are likely accessing an array out of bounds. Try `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`, rerun and report. After that we need a fuul [mcve] not just few lines.,

Comment: Well, you admit you *have tried **some** array bound checking* now I suggest you go wild and try array bound checking everywhere and all the time until you are certain that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Running with -g -Wall -fcheck=all returned numerous warnings, as well as some actual errors. On execution, it is clear that I am exceeding some array bounds. I am trying to sort through this but I will come back with responses - thanks for your help. In short, it turns out that even many of my ~95% working programs (that were occasionally pathological) have some array issues as well. Some recurrent warnings: Extension: exponent-letter ‘q’ in real-literal-constant at (1), undefined labels, unused variables/dummy arguments.